# Compare DateTime in Apex

Tags: apex, datetime

I have created 2 dateTime Instances as below to compare DateTime.now() if it is greater than 8 pm and less than 7:59 am then I want to execute some code but it is difficult to compare dateTime as the date will be changed after 12 am.

```
DateTime eightPm = DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(20, 0, 0, 0));
DateTime seven59Am = DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(07, 59, 0, 0));
```

Can someone please help me to compare the dateTime.Now() with above 2 instances so that I can check if the dateTime.now() is greater than 8pm and less than 7 am(next day)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare time component from Date.Now() and based on that take the decision

```
Time t = Datetime.now().time();
if((t.hour()>19 && t.hour()<=23) 
   && (t.minute()>0 && t.minute() <=59)
   && (t.second()>0 && t.second() <=59))
   {
        //current time is on same date
        DateTime eightPm = DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(20, 0, 0, 0));
        DateTime seven59Am = DateTime.newInstance(date.today().addDays(1), time.newInstance(07, 59, 0, 0));
   }else
   {
       DateTime eightPm = DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(20, 0, 0, 0));
        DateTime seven59Am = DateTime.newInstance(date.today(), time.newInstance(07, 59, 0, 0));

   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response but this won't work as after 12 am I don't want to compare the date with next day's date, it should be today's 7:59 am

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you so much!